# Only first For loop called

Tags: iphone, for-loop, subview

I have two for loops that add subviews to the view.  The first one adds all the subviews, but the second for loop is not even executed!  Whats Up?

```
- (void)createBoxes
{
    for (int i; i<5; i++) {
        GameBox *box = [[GameBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i * 64) + 7, 50, 50, 50)];
        [self.view addSubview:box];
    }
    for (int e; e<5; e++) {
        GameBox *box1 = [[GameBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((e * 64) + 7, 107, 50, 50)];
        [self.view addSubview:box1];
    }
}
```

Comment: try placing a call for NSLOG(@"LOOP");
maybe it does get called and the problem is with the creation of the boxes

Comment: nope.  When i logged it nothing happened.  Skipping it completely...

Comment: when you end the first loop what is the value of e is it >=5

Comment: Yes, set the values to 0 first, or they will be some arbitrary value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Proper way would be to initialize variables :

```
int i = 0;
int e = 0;
```

Otherwise you never know which value you'll get.

Comment: +1. Local variables always need to be initialized. If you check it in the debugger, e could be something like 3728632873, in which case it's most certainly not less than 5, and you skip your loop!

Answer (score 3):

Why are you not initialising your loop variables? These are not standard for loops at all.